# calling paginate function of laravel on a array?

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

Here is my controller function where i am paginating my results

```
 public function showallUsers() {

    $user = User::getUsers()->simplePaginate(5);
    return view('sellerTable', compact('user'));
}
```

I am using  Eloquent queries in my models to get data from database , here is my **getUser** method in the User model.

```
 protected static function getUsers() {
    $data = User::where('role', '=', 'seller')
                    ->where('archive', '=', 0)->get(['id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_no', 'gender', 'facebook_id', 'gmail_id', 'email', 'braintree_customer_id', 'role']);
    return (!empty($data)) ? $data->toArray() : array();
}
```

When i use to hit my controller function the following error comes

```
   Call to a member function simplePaginate() on array
```

It is comming because i am returning an array in Model User to UserController . Laravel is not allowing me to call a simplePaginate Function on an array , any ideas that how can i call laravel Paginator on an array ?

Answer (score 1):

You made collection to array and trying to use simplePaginage method which is for collection not array.

Use `simplePaginate` inside model method before converting to array.

```
protected static function getUsers() {
    $data = User::where('role', '=', 'seller')
                    ->where('archive', '=', 0)->get(['id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_no', 'gender', 'facebook_id', 'gmail_id', 'email', 'braintree_customer_id', 'role']);
    $data = $data->simplePaginate(5);
    return (!empty($data)) ? $data->toArray() : array();
}
```

and use in controller like this

```
$user = User::getUsers();
```

Comment: Now it working perfectly, but links() or render is mot working in my view , kindly give suggestion in this case.

Comment: @user7597883 : You can make another question with fully detail as here no detail contain in your current question regarding view's problem.

Comment: it's again give error that simplePaginate does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to return an array instead of collections.

Change your function like this

```
protected static function getUsers() {
    $data = User::where('role', '=', 'seller')
                    ->where('archive', '=', 0)->get(['id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_no', 'gender', 'facebook_id', 'gmail_id', 'email', 'braintree_customer_id', 'role']);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I have to return an array because of my logic in views depends on array